# failed to import tensorflow (module 'tensorflow_core.contrib' has no attribute 'cudnn_rnn_ops')

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

So I am trying to import [cudnn_rnn_ops](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.2/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/ops/cudnn_rnn_ops.py) like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.15.2/tensorflow/contrib/cudnn_rnn/python/layers/cudnn_rnn.py#L20). But it just gives me the error as title.

> module 'tensorflow_core.contrib' has no attribute 'cudnn_rnn_ops'

Any advice?

Comment: have you install tensorflow-gpu+cudnn library+cuda toolkit ??

Comment: @Jai yes, tensorflow-gpu(1.15.2), cudnn(7.4.2), cuda(10.0). I can actually train model with gpu.

Comment: This module does not seem to be part of the public API: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn

Answer (score 0):

`from tensorflow.contrib.cudnn_rnn.python.ops import cudnn_rnn_ops` works with Tensorflow-gpu 1.15 on Google colab.

Issue might be because of CUDA/cuDNN version compatibility and also check the nvidia driver version.